# How to Exit Python Code when XML File is empty (XML to CSV conversion)

Tags: python, xml, csv

if the XML file is empty i.e. no root element, how to handle in python? When there are XML records, below Python code works fine but whenever XML file empty, conversion process files. I am looking for an exit instead of failing the process.

XML:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns2:exportEmpData xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.example.com/"/>
```

Python Code:

```
import xml
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:/emp/emplist.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

Emp_data = open('C:/emp/emplist.csv', 'wb')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(Emp_data)
emp_head = []

count = 0
for member in root.findall('emplist'):
emp_nodes = []
if count == 0:
  empId = member.find('empId').tag
  emp_head.append(empId)
  fullName = member.find('fullName').tag
  emp_head.append(fullName)
  currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').tag
  emp_head.append(currentAddress)
  csvwriter.writerow(emp_head)
  count = count + 1

  empId = member.find('empId').text
  emp_nodes.append(empId)
  fullName = member.find('fullName').text
  emp_nodes.append(fullName)
  currentAddress = member.find('currentAddress').attrib.get('city')
  emp_nodes.append(currentAddress)
  csvwriter.writerow(emp_nodes)
Emp_data.close()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Wouldn't `root.findall('emplist')` return an empty in that case? If so, then you could just check the length of what it returns to see if there are any member records. i.e. `members = root.findall('emplist')`, `if not members: exit()`

Comment: Thanks, martineau. I have tried exit(), quit(), sys.exit(), raise SystemExit but none of them are working. Is there any other way to exit without erroring out?

Comment: You could put all your code in a function (ie: `main()`), then use return

Comment: Thanks for your response olinox14. Can you please provide an example? I am new to programming.

Comment: Enric: If you don't know how to create a functions yet, then I strongly suggest you ***immediately*** stop what you are doing and go learn about them.